# NoUiSlider's slider not working in react application

Tags: reactjs, nouislider

I am trying to use noUiSlider in my react application. The slider show up but the slider is not functional. It doesn't move. This is how I initialized the slider in my componentDidMount method.

```
 componentDidMount(){


        var noUi_slider = document.getElementById('noUiSlider');
        noUiSlider.create(noUi_slider, {
            start: 40,
            connect: true,
            range: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            }
        });

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.  When I click anywhere  on slider timeline the time changes when I inspect it. But the slider (pointer) is not moving.

Comment: Hi there. I notice a number of your questions are quite chatty, and are leaning a bit towards begging and pleading for help. We know you need help, so "please help me" and how long you've been stuck isn't necessary, and you may find material of this kind puts some folks off answering. I tend to recommend that you keep questions as succinct as you can, and remember that everyone here is a volunteer. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a fix? Can you please update the answer if so?